# problem about limit

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: https://imgur.stack.imgur.com/S2pAN.png]

My interpretation is that $f(r)=0$, $f(x)$ is a $4$-times differentiable function, and $f'(x) > 0 $.

Let \begin{align*}F(x)&=f(x)f'(x)^{-1/2},\\ G(x) &= x -F(x)/F'(x)\end{align*}

The problem is find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to r}(G(x)-r)/(x-r)^2$.

I tried to use L'Hopital but it requires $F^{(3)}(x)$.

I was able to calculated $F''(x)$.

Do I need to calculate $F^{(3)}(x)$, or is there another good solution?

Comment: So the problem is to find, $$ \lim_{x\to r}\left(\frac{x-\frac{(f(x)f'(x))^{-1/2}}{\left((f(x)f'(x))^{-1/2}\right)'}-r}{(x-r)^{2}}\right)$$ when $f(r)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry i'm not used to mathjax.

Comment: Well, here in MSE the policy is that you must show your effort in solving the problem. This is important so that we can better help you.

Comment: I understand. I'll write it asap.

Comment: When I try to click on the link it says that my connection is not private. Is this a problem on my end or with Stack Exchange?

Comment: @bobeyt6 Seems to work for me. Unfortunately, the writing is in a script I cannot read (I think it is Korean).

Comment: It is Tokyo univ. Graduated School Entrance Examination problem. It is Japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My translation of the question matches yours (noting that questions 1 and 2 are asking to express $F'(x)$ and $F''(x)$ in terms of $f$ and its derivatives).

We don't need to calculate $F^{(3)}(x)$, thankfully, but it *does* help to know that it exists and is continuous at $x = r$, which we can claim because by extension of the answers to the first two questions it's going to be some polynomial of $f, f', f'', f''', f''''$ divided by $f'(x)$ raised to some power.

However, what we *do* need is to calculate a few derivatives of $G$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}G(x) & = & x - \frac{F(x)}{F'(x)} \\
G(r) & = & r - \frac{F(r)}{F'(r)} = r \\
G'(x) & = & 1 - \frac{F'(x)}{F'(x)} + \frac{F(x) F''(x)}{(F'(x))^2} \\
& = & \frac{F(x) F''(x)}{(F'(x))^2} \\
G'(r) & = & \frac{F(r) F''(r)}{(F'(r))^2} = 0 \\
G''(x) & = & \frac{F'(x) F''(x)}{(F'(x))^2} + \frac{F(x) F''(x)}{(F'(x))^2} - \frac{2 F(x) (F''(x))^2}{(F'(x))^3} \\
& = & \frac{F''(x)}{F'(x)} + \frac{F(x) F''(x)}{(F'(x))^2} - \frac{2 F(x) (F''(x))^2}{(F'(x))^3}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now we can tackle the limit. We're going to apply L'Hospital's rule twice, once on each of the first two lines (since we have a $\frac{0}{0}$ form both times).

$$\begin{eqnarray} \lim_{x \rightarrow r} \frac{G(x) - r}{(x - r)^2} & = & \lim_{x \rightarrow r} \frac{G'(x)}{2(x - r)} \\
& = & \lim_{x \rightarrow r} \frac{G''(x)}{2} \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow r} \left(\frac{F''(x)}{F'(x)} + \frac{F(x) F''(x)}{(F'(x))^2} - \frac{2 F(x) (F''(x))^2}{(F'(x))^3} \right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow r} \frac{F''(x)}{F'(x)} \\
& = & \frac{F''(r)}{2 F'(r)}
\end{eqnarray}$$

And if your answers to questions 1 and 2 were anything like mine you'll have $F'(r) > 0$ and $F''(r) = 0$, resulting in the final limit being 0.